# How to remove index.php in codeigniter when changing root directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got moved the Application and System folders below the root directory as described here. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html But I'm not sure how to get the urls to work properly with the new directory locations.

```
/root/var/
    `-- www
        |-- siteroot
        |       |-- .htaccess
        |       |-- index.php
        |       |-- style.css
        |       |-- script.js
        |-- application/
        |-- system/
```

currently this way
http://example.com/index.php/about

this is the way I want it but currently it shows a 404
http://example.com/about

this is my current .htaccess file. It removed the index.php before I moved the folders below the root, now it will still remove the index.php but none of the controllers work without the index.php

```
################################################
#other hacks can be found at http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^../system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^../application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

################################################
#http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/92609/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after putting htaccess file just go to application/config/config.php and change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and also in htaccess file either comment following line

```
#RewriteBase /
```

or make it

```
RewriteBase /siteroot/
```

Comment: I already have configured the above file. The below answer doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: if your application and system folder are out of your siteroot folder then you have modifiy your index.php file, just find $system_path = 'system'; and change it to $system_path = '../system'; same for application

Comment: turns out my apache config file said AllowOverride None